Импорт библиотек в pycharm
Скачал новую версию pycharm и python 13-ую версию. И вот такая ситуация, код работает, numpy работает, pandas работает, но pandas подчеркнут красным. В старых версиях такого не было, что это такое?


Надо просто перезалить путь до интерпретатора

Такая библиотека поддерживается только в профессиональной версии pycharm, а у тебя, скорее всего, версия Community.

pandas любой версией PyCharm поддерживается. Могут не поддерживаться какие-нибудь фишки типа встроенного просмотра датафреймов при отладке (из головы взял, может и в Pro нет такой фишки), но сама библиотека поддерживается и PyCharm Community.
